# Pandas dataframe merge returns NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, jupyter

I'm having issues merging dataframes. The merge returns NaN values and I'm not sure why!

[image: df1]

[image: df2]

Resulting merge after running `pd.merge`:

```
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Date', 'City_State'], how='left')
```

[image: merged_df]

I tried checking if it was a dtypes issue but the dtypes of 'Date' and 'City_State' are the same for both.

Comment: `df2` has extra space `' '` after `','` in `'City_State'`  while `df1` doesn't

Comment: @QuangHoang beat me to it :)